# Eclipse regex search not returning multiple matches

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have an xml file that contains, among other tags, a sequence of `page` tags that look like the following (the ellipses are just to show content that is not included):

```
<page1 ...>
   ...
</page>

<page2 ...>
   ...
</page>

<page3 ...>
   ...
</page>
```

This is my Eclipse IDE regex search expression:

```
(?s)<page.*</page>
```

The search results are returning one match; everything between `<page1` and the very last `</page>` element.  I'm trying to get it to return 3 matches, one for each  element.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Make your regex to do a non-greedy match `(?s)<page.*?<\/page>`

Comment: wow.  that worked.  If you want to put this as the answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @AvinashRaj If I wanted to match all <page> tags EXCEPT those that have the <queue> tag inside them, how could I do that?  I've tried (?s)<page.*?(?!<queue>).*?</page> but it still matches all <page> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is greedy by default. That is, it matches all the characters as far as it can (longest possible match). By adding the  quantifier `?` next to the `*` forces the regex engine to do a non-greedy match (shortest possible match).

```
(?s)<page.*?<\/page>
```

`(?s)` Dotall modifier which makes the dot in your regex to match even line breaks.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mI7qF6/2)